# Getting NSArray empty crash when trying to segue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I don't understand the co-relation between this Query I'm doing and a button I'm trying to execute in order to perform a segue.

**Here is the Query**

```
- (void) queryData {


    float navBarHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;

    float statusHeight = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height;

    float tabBarHeight = self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;

    CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;


    PFObject *queryPhotos = self.sellerObject;
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Photo"];

    if (self.categoryChosenBool == NO) {
        [query whereKey:@"userTookPhoto" equalTo:queryPhotos];
        [query includeKey:@"userTookPhoto"];
        [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

    }
    else if (self.categoryChosenBool == YES)
    {
        [query whereKey:@"userTookPhoto" equalTo:queryPhotos];
        [query includeKey:@"userTookPhoto"];
        [query whereKey:@"category" containsString:self.chosenCategoryText];
        [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    }

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error)
    {
    if (!error) {
        imageFilesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];

                    if ((imageFilesArray.count % 3)) {
                        CGFloat height = imageFilesArray.count / 3;

                        CGFloat roundedUp = ceilf(height + 1);

                        NSLog(@"1 %f",roundedUp + 1);


                        if (screenSize.height < 569) {
                            NSLog(@"iphone 5 or 4");
                            CGFloat cellHeight = roundedUp * 106.5;


                            [_productCollectionView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, _filterButton.frame.origin.y + _filterButton.frame.size.height + 15, self.view.frame.size.width, cellHeight)];

                            [_contentView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, cellHeight + _productCollectionView.frame.origin.y)];
                            [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, cellHeight + _productCollectionView.frame.origin.y + statusHeight + navBarHeight + tabBarHeight)];


                        }
                        else if (screenSize.height > 666){
                            NSLog(@"iphone 6 or 6Plus");
                            CGFloat cellHeight = roundedUp * 125;

                            [_productCollectionView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, _filterButton.frame.origin.y + _filterButton.frame.size.height + 15, self.view.frame.size.width, cellHeight)];

                            [_contentView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, cellHeight + _productCollectionView.frame.origin.y)];
                            [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, cellHeight + _productCollectionView.frame.origin.y + statusHeight + navBarHeight + tabBarHeight)];


                        }


                    }else{
                        CGFloat height = imageFilesArray.count / 3;

                        CGFloat roundedUp = ceilf(height);

                        NSLog(@"2 %f",roundedUp);


                        if (screenSize.height < 569) {
                            NSLog(@"iphone 5 or 4");
                            CGFloat cellHeight = roundedUp * 106.5;

                            if (objects.count < 1) {
                                [_productCollectionView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, _filterButton.frame.origin.y + _filterButton.frame.size.height + 15, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - tabBarHeight - statusHeight - navBarHeight - _filterButton.frame.origin.y - _filterButton.frame.size.height )];
                            }
                            else{

                            [_productCollectionView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, _filterButton.frame.origin.y + _filterButton.frame.size.height + 15, self.view.frame.size.width, cellHeight)];

                            [_contentView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, cellHeight + _productCollectionView.frame.origin.y)];
                            [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, cellHeight + _productCollectionView.frame.origin.y + statusHeight + navBarHeight + tabBarHeight)];
                            }

                        }
                        else if (screenSize.height > 666){
                            NSLog(@"iphone 6 or 6Plus");
                            CGFloat cellHeight = roundedUp * 125;

                            if (objects.count < 1) {
                                [_productCollectionView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, _filterButton.frame.origin.y + _filterButton.frame.size.height + 15, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - tabBarHeight - statusHeight - navBarHeight - _filterButton.frame.origin.y - _filterButton.frame.size.height )];
                            }
                            else{

                                [_productCollectionView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, _filterButton.frame.origin.y + _filterButton.frame.size.height + 15, self.view.frame.size.width, cellHeight)];

                                [_contentView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, cellHeight + _productCollectionView.frame.origin.y)];
                                [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, cellHeight + _productCollectionView.frame.origin.y + statusHeight + navBarHeight + tabBarHeight)];
                            }


                        }

                    }

         [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
        [_productCollectionView reloadData];
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];

    }

    }];

}
```

The button is executed by:

```
-(void)executeSegue
{
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"nextView" sender:self];

}
```

In this case the query is empty, but I dont understand why the method is crashing due to that.

But when I comment out the Query, it performs the segue perfectly fine.

Comment: What is the exception message? Which line does it crash on?

Comment: How do i check what line?

Answer (score 0):

You can't call this in background thread:

```
[SVProgressHUD dismiss];
[_productCollectionView reloadData];
[self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
```

Use it in main thread. Try to use this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
   [_productCollectionView reloadData];
   [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
});
```

Comment: Parse SDK  dispatches its completion blocks onto the main thread already

Comment: And I cannot find where do you call executeSegue. Call it only in main thread

Comment: @Konstantin I call executeSegue with a UIButton

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'

Comment: Check that you segue identifier is correct and supported from your viewController

Comment: The crash says that you tired to get some objects from empty array. Try to find place where you use your array, add breakpoints and debug